# How to Insert Facebook Details into Database after Facebook Login in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook, android-studio

I am currently developing an Android app. I have created a Facebook login which displays the user's picture and everything once logged in. I am planning on developing a chat function within the app (not facebook chat) using the user's Facebook details. I was stuck on how to save the user's details to a MySQL database once they have logged in? I have researched tirelessly without any success on my exact issue.

I am not asking for code, but rather an insight on how to do it or to point me in the right direction to a tutorial on how to do it.

I am new to PHP and SQL so therefore do not have experience in this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just send the access token to the server, and then request the data you want from the API there. Then store it into your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP for API, then you can write one API for login.

Flow will be :

1) Facebook Login from Android app, you will get FaceBook id, name, Facebook profile pic image URl

2) Write an API in PHP which will take FaceBook id, name, Facebook profile pic image URl as input and store those in MySQL DB.

You can **[Refer](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)** article for Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL. **This article is just for reference.**

Comment: Yes, that sounds good to me. But considering I am new to PHP, I am not quite sure how to do this? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: are you aware about API / web services ?

Comment: Yes I am aware of both

Comment: Then write an API which will take FaceBook ID etc as input and store that into DB, then responds success.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me something that after logout how we will again login the user because we have not any password of the user in the database. We only have FacebookID, name and URL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is small info to store use SHARED PREFERENCE

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("email", madhu@gmail.com);
editor.commit();
```